# CSS Expand the width of the div to overlay the div on left

Tags: html, css

I am stuck on a CSS issue for a while. I searched other posts, but I still didn't find a solution.

As shown in the screenshot below, I want to expand the grey date bar to the left most. However, there is a div on the left as shown in the green area. I tried to set the `width:100%`, but it cannot cover the left green areas.

[Screenshot for the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE6Ey.png)

There is also a solution to use `transform: scale(1.5, 1)`, but this will change the shapes of the date words and number which make them look bad.

Can I get some help to extend the date bar?
CSS for date bar:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
background: #ebedee;
width: 100%;
border: none;
```

Comment: Can you give us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Do you know the width of the green part you want to cover?

Comment: @LucaNeri IT is 97 px. Thanks

Comment: Could you do `width: calc(100% + 97px)`?

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets of your HTML and CSS.

Comment: @LucaNeri Thanks this works with setting absolute position and `left:-97`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Luca Neri.

The solution is to set:

```
width: calc(100% + 109px);
position: absolute;
left: -97px;
```